# Creating a popup

Tags: templates

I'm starting in plugin development for wordpress.

I have a php script that outputs to pdf in my plugin.

I am trying to figure out two things:

1. How do I present the page without the wordpress templates, but with the security.  Meaning I do not want the headers or footers on the page.
2. How do I set the link to open as a new window, either tab, window, or popup?

### UPDATE #1

I am starting with the mPDF example:

```
<?php

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetColumns(2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Some text...</p><columnbreak /><p>Next column...</p>');
$mpdf=Output();

?>
```

I can make the pdf by itself, but not as an output in wordpress.  That's my problem.

Comment: What have you coded so far? Please post your code that relates to your question.

Comment: All I have is the examples from the mPDF manual.  I put the example above.  Sorry, but I am really beginning my plugin experience here.